# how to show content using toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I made a simple demo in JQM. In this demo there is a lot of space that is occupied by buttons and a textfield.

So I tried to hide the content with the idea to show it when a button is clicked.

I want that content only to show on button click and hide and again when the user clicks the button. Given picture I need to toggle. Here is the content I need to toggle on button click:

```
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="header">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="new_h"><a href="#" class="active"><i class="new"></i>New</a>
                </li>
                <li class="export_h"><a href="#"><i class="export "></i>Export</a>
                </li>
                <li class="import_h"><a href="#"><i class="import "></i>Import</a>
                </li>
                <div class="cb"></div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <article class="testsuitbox">
            <h1>TestSuite Name</h1>
            <input name="" type="text" class="txtfield" id="testSuiteId"/>
        </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you need to "toggle" the content, simply use `.toggle()`.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Docs example:

HTML

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

jQuery

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/27/ In this I hide the contend now I want to show the contend

Comment: I'm not sure which content you want to show exactly. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6G4w/. Three buttons, each toggles different content. I think you can work with it.

Comment: I need to toggle that div <div style="" class="hide" id="toglediv">

Comment: You forgot the dollar sign before `('#toglediv')`. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/p7xaC/. It works but you CSS is not perfect I suppose.

Comment: I only use this css .hide{
    display:none;
}
.show{
}………………………..And rest css is not useful

Comment: @lessugar your fiddle also not toggle the div

Comment: Yes it does. Take a look at the scrollbar change when you click the toggle button. The content shows and hides, it just does that below the window frame. Click the toggle button and scroll down to the bottom of the window. That's what I meant with the imperfect CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54842/discussion-between-user2535959-and-lesssugar).